# Git - remote branches forked repository

Tags: git

I created a fork on github of an existing project that I want to develop according to own needs. But I want to regularly synchronize own repository from the upstream repository. So I'm interested (only) in branch upstream/master. Are any other remote branches can safely delete?

Comment: I don't completely understand the question, it seems like you are aksing if you can delete the branches you are not interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to pull from `upstream/master`, then you only need the branch which is tracking that remote branch. All other branches are superfluous and can be deleted.

You can then create local branches for your own work that are not tracking any remote branch.